# modified javascript code unable to be saved

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, database

I'm working on a hangman game using `html`, `css`, `js` and `php`.

1. Using `php` you get a `random word` from a `xampp mysql server` in an `unordered display`.
2. By using `javascript`, `input boxes` are automatically created depending on the `length` of the word.
3. After filling all input boxes a `submit` button appears.

The problem is that before implementing php functionality to get an item from the DB I was testing my app only with `js` with a given word `var word = "Rhodes"` . After implementing `php` and managing to `display a randomized word from the DB` in my screen and modifying my js code  I also got the `word ="Rhodes"` next to my random word and only input boxes corresponding to `"Rhodes" length` instead of the new word .

> In other words the code I deleted still runs like it was never
> modified .

I have my new code below . With js I get the php word to create input boxes . It doesn't work and the old code is displayed .

```js
function hangman(){
    var island = document.getElementById("random-island"); //the given word that is supposed to be found 
    createSpaces(island);
    const inputLists = document.querySelectorAll("input");
    document.querySelectorAll("input").forEach(el => {
      el.addEventListener('input', evt => {
          const showButton = [...inputLists].filter(ip => ip.value.trim() !== '').length === inputLists.length;
          document.getElementById('submitbtn').style.display = showButton ? 'block' : 'none';
      });
    });
}


function createSpaces(text){
    for(var i=0;i<text.length;i++){
      var space = document.createElement("input");
      space.setAttribute("class" , "dash");
      document.getElementById("hangman-container").appendChild(space);
    }
}
```

```css
.transparent-box {
    border:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:10%;
    left:15%;
    background-color:black;
    height:500px;
    width:70%;
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.transparent-box p {
    color:white;  
    text-align:center;

}

.transparent-box h1 {
    color:white;
    position: relative;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:20px;
    top:30px;
}


#hangman-container {
    position: relative;
    width:auto;
    top:30%;
    left:0%;
    background-color: transparent;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}


.dash {
    margin:0;
    padding:20px;
    align-items: flex-start;
    width:4%;
    border:none;
    border-radius: 5%;
    background-color: turquoise;
    color:red;
    font-size:40px;
}

.dash:focus {
    opacity:0.8;
}

#submitbtn {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top:200%;
    left:80%;
    float:right; 
}
```

```html
<body onload = hangman()>
   <div class = "transparent-box" id = "t-box">
      <p>Play here </p>
      <h1 id = "hidden-word">The word is :
         <?php
            $link = @mysqli_connect('localhost' , 'root' , 'password' ,'dbname');
            if(!$link){
                echo 'Error connecting to DB';
                exit;
            }
            
            $query = "SELECT island_name FROM dodecanese ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
            $result = @mysqli_query($link, $query);
            if(!$result){
                echo 'There is an issue with the DB';
                exit;
            }
            $row = @mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            echo '<span id = "random-island">'.str_shuffle($row['island_name']). '</span>';
            
            ?>
      </h1>
      <form id  = "hangman-container" method="POST">
         <button type = "submit" class = "hide" id="submitbtn">Submit</button>
      </form>
   </div>
</body>
```

I would appreciate your help with this . Thank you in advance .

Comment: Check your javascript with Developer tools, probably your "deleted" code is still there.

Comment: @ArielAlvarado There was nothing to see

Comment: So, no old code? Only the new code is there?

Comment: @ArielAlvarado The old . I  checked better . But why ? What should I do ?

Comment: Try clearing the cache, if that doesn't work, check if the code is updated in your server (/var/www/your-site probably)

Comment: @ArielAlvarado It worked

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully understand what your actual question is.

But if I understood correctly - you would like PHP to play a role in this game.
(i.e. PHP to connect to the database instead of javascript doing everything itself by having a big list of words in the array, pick it up, doing checks all in client-side).

Then what I would suggest having at least 3 files (not mentioning assets):

1. Index.html
2. NewWordGenerator.php
3. WordChecker.php

Additionally, I would suggest you to spend some time if possible familiarising with ajax. jQuery might give you an easier entry point for ajax.

**Suggested workflow:**

Index.html file that has a start button, js + ajax code, placeholders, styling etc.

When a visitor would press "start the game" button, it would trigger ajax to make a call to NewWordGenerator.php file which would connect to the database and get any random word from your database, which would be displayed in index.html when ajax is successful, js to "cut" the word into letters and put it to placeholders/form etc.

When a player would click submit button, javascript/jQuery would prevent default form submission, send user input via ajax to WordChecker.php which would be handling checking the word and giving the result that is returned and displayed in index.html.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I have succeeded in getting data from sql using php . The problem is when I modified my js code no changes where saved and the program would run like js was not modified